# Multiple subfaction leaders

Tags: werewolv.es

Is it possible to have more than one Illuminati, Mason, Inquisition, or Cult Leader in a game? If so, would they still have their individual recruits or would it be combined as if there was only one leader?
Would it also effect roles such as Mason sergeant, who gets a recruit if their leader is dead? If a scenario where one leader would die and not the other were to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple sub-faction leaders make 1 large sub-faction (See: ext-100 when Mason Leader was introduced).

Each leader has their usual pool to recruit from (X recruits per leader) but they all join the same large sub-faction.

Mason Sergeant only activates when all leaders are dead.

Other roles that interact with leaders (eg, Lost Mason) will also work when finding any leader.